# LaTeX3: unable to convert space separated list into clist

Tags: latex3

I want to convert a space separated list of items, given as argument to a function, into a clist variable in order to iterate over them. However, I am not able to create a usable clist variable as the following code example demonstrates. `\clist_map_inline:Nn` always takes the whole list instead of separating the elements. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn\parselist:n{
  \tl_set:Nx\l_csv_tl{#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn\l_csv_tl{~}{,}
  \clist_set:Nx\l_csv_clist\l_csv_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn\l_csv_clist{
    \noindent Name:~#1\par
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\def\csv{fred jane albert}
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \parselist:n\csv
  \parselist:n{john~peter~linda}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Comment: You must use `Name:~##1`. With `#1` you are getting the outer argument.

Comment: Unless you need a clist for other reasons, I'd use a sequence and `\seq_set_split:Nnn` here.

Comment: Also, you are slightly mis-behaving here with the arg spec. I'd say your first use of `\parselist:n` should be either a `V` or `N` function (little in it here).

Comment: @Joseph Wright: Thanks for mentioning the sequence data type. I like the suggested `\seq_set_split:Nnn` very much, but is it stable enough to be used in a public package?

Comment: @AlexanderGrahn One for LaTeX-L! I'd say that if we add something 'experimental', what will get it made 'non-experimental' is good use cases. So give feedback on what you use and we can move them. I'll alter the status of `\seq_set_split:Nnn` over the next few days: it's definitely useful.

Comment: @JosephWright: Given that Alexander uses `\tl_set:Nx`, the function should probably be called `\parselist:x`. I think `\seq_set_split:Nnn` is stable enough (at the implementation level) to be moved to non-experimental. Decide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the error myself. Using `##1` in the function body of `\clist_map_inline:Nn` does the trick. Otherwise the original argument as given to `\parselist:n` is used.