# How to check if a datatool db has an existing member

Tags: datatool

I would like to suppress duplicated entries in a list.  The lists are comma separated lists defined in a macro as in my earlier question on [Sorting Comma Separated Lists defined with, or without macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52640/sorting-comma-separated-lists-defined-with-or-without-macro).

My current approach is to use [the `datatool` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/datatool).  The most obvious method to me seemed to use `\DTLgetlocation`. But, that yields the following error if the member does not exist (uncommenting the commented lines in the MWE to see this):

> Package datatool Error: There is no element `XYZ` in database `duplicates`

Perhaps I should not be using the `datatool` package for this and use an entirely different approach?

### Update:

The code below has been updated to do an additional test via a `\foreach` loop (with and without a macro defined list).  This also necessitated the addition of `\dtlexpandnewvalue` in the `\IfIsInDB` macro.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=15in]{geometry}% so output fits on "one" page
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgffor}%   Added for expanded test

\newcommand*{\DBKey}{Value}%

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDuplicatesDB}[1]{% 
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}%
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[2]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = member to be added to DB
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{\DBKey}{#2}%
}%
\newcommand*{\IfIsInDB}[4]{%
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    % #2 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
    % #3 = code to execute if member is in DB
    % #4 = code to execute if member is not in DB
    %
    \dtlexpandnewvalue% Added in update.
    %
    \DTLgetlocation{\RowIndex}{\ColIndex}{#1}{#2}%
    %row=\RowIndex \quad col=\ColIndex\par
    \ifnum\RowIndex>0\relax%
        #3%
    \else%
        #4%
        \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2}
    \fi%
}%
    
\begin{document}
\InitalizeDuplicatesDB{duplicates}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{DEF}

Current db:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{ABC}{ABC is a duplicate}{ABC added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{DEF}{DEF is a duplicate}{DEF added DB}\par
%\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{XYZ}{XYZ is a duplicate}{XYZ added DB}\par

\medskip
Current db (before foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

%% Following tests added in update.
%\medskip\par\noindent
%Testing with a non-macro defined list (ABC, DEF should not be ``added", and MMM should only be ``added" once):\par
%\foreach \x in {ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}{%
%    \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\x}{\x~is a duplicate}{\x~added DB}\par
%}%
%
%Current db (after foreach - no macro):\par
%\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
%
%\medskip\par\noindent
%Testing with a macro defined list: (ABC, DEF should not be "added", and NNN should only be ``added" once)\par
%\newcommand*{\ListMembers}{ABC, XXX, DEF, NNN, NNN, YYY}%
%\foreach \x in \ListMembers {%
%    \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\x}{\x~is a duplicate}{\x~added DB}\par
%}
%
%Current db (after foreach - macro defn):\par
%\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\foreach` loops execute their code in a group for each step, so they are useless when something must be changed "globally", as is the case for your databases.

Here's a way using the patch proposed by Werner; but I used a different command to patch, in order not to change the functionality of `\DTLgetlocation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=15in]{geometry}% so output fits on "one" page
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachin}{ m +m } % long arguments
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%%% Werner's patch
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Patch \DTLgetlocation to gobble the error
\let\ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation\DTLgetlocation
\patchcmd{\ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation}% <cmd>
  {\PackageError}% <search>
  {\@gobbletwo}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\def\@@dtlnovalue{\@dtlnovalue} 
%%%

\newcommand*{\DBKey}{Value}

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDuplicatesDB}[1]{% 
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[2]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = member to be added to DB
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{\DBKey}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\IfIsInDB}[4]{% %New definition!
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    % #2 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
    % #3 = code to execute if member is in DB
    % #4 = code to execute if member is not in DB
    \ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation{\RowIndex}{\ColIndex}{#1}{#2}%
    %row=\RowIndex \quad col=\ColIndex\par
    \ifx\RowIndex\@@dtlnovalue
        #4%
        \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2}%
    \else
        #3
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\InitalizeDuplicatesDB{duplicates}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{DEF}

Current db:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{ABC}{ABC is a duplicate}{ABC added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{DEF}{DEF is a duplicate}{DEF added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{XYZ}{XYZ is a duplicate}{XYZ added DB}\par

\medskip
Current db (before foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

% Following tests added in update.
\medskip\par\noindent
Testing with a non-macro defined list (ABC, DEF should not be ``added", and MMM should only be ``added" once):\par
\foreachin {ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}{%
    \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{#1}{#1~is a duplicate}{#1~added DB}\par
}

Current db (after foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\end{document}
```

As you see, the syntax of `\foreachin` is very similar to `\foreach\x in`; instead of `\x` you use `#1` in the code part.

### A variant

If you want to be able to pass the list to `\foreachin` as a macro, say

```
\newcommand{\mylist}{ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}

\foreachin{\mylist}{\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{#1}{#1~is a duplicate}{#1~added DB}}
```

then change the definition of `\foreachin`:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachin}{ m +m } % long arguments
 {
  \clist_map_inline:on { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn {o}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

## A completely different approach

Instead of `datatool` you might use the *property list* data type of `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\InitializeDuplicatesDB}{m}
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_grill_#1_prop }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddMemberToDB}{ m m }
 % #1 = name of DB
 % #2 = member to be added to DB
 {
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_grill_#1_prop } { #2 } { Value }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\IfIsInDB}{mmmm}
 % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
 % #2 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
 % #3 = code to execute if member is in DB
 % #4 = code to execute if member is not in DB
 {
  \prop_get:cnNTF { g_grill_#1_prop } { #2 } \l_tmpa_tl
   { #3 }
   { \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2} #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DTLdisplaydb}{m}
 {
  \prop_map_inline:cn { g_grill_#1_prop } { ##1\par }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\InitializeDuplicatesDB{duplicates}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{DEF}

Current db:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{ABC}{ABC is a duplicate}{ABC added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{DEF}{DEF is a duplicate}{DEF added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{XYZ}{XYZ is a duplicate}{XYZ added DB}\par

\medskip
Current db (before foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
\end{document}
```

The `for each` cycle can then be defined just as before. Of course, in a real application, you'll add an argument to `\AddMemberToDB` (to replace the common `Value` given to each key).

---

## And now for something completely different

If what you really need is to maintain a comma separated list, adding one element at a time unless it's already present, you can do with the clist data type of `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewList}{ m }
  {
   \clist_new:c { g_pg_#1_clist }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddToList}{ m m }
 {
  \clist_if_in:cnTF { g_pg_#1_clist } { #2 }
   { #2~is~a~duplicate~in~\texttt{#1}\par }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:cn { g_pg_#1_clist } { #2 }
    #2~added~to~\texttt{#1}\par
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowList}{ m }
 {
  List~\texttt{#1}~contains\par
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_pg_#1_clist } { ##1\par }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\foreachin}{ m m } % long arguments
 {
  \clist_map_inline:Vn #1 { #2 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \clist_map_inline:nn {V}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\NewList{duplicates} % allocate a new list
\AddToList{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddToList{duplicates}{DEF}

\ShowList{duplicates}

\AddToList{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddToList{duplicates}{XYZ}

\ShowList{duplicates}

\newcommand{\mylist}{ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}

\foreachin{\mylist}{\AddToList{duplicates}{#1}}

\ShowList{duplicates}

\end{document}
```

The output will be

[image]

If you don't care about doing something if the added entries are duplicate and want only to have uniqueness, you can use a simpler strategy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewList}{ m }
  {
   \clist_new:c { g_pg_#1_clist }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\AddToList}{ s m m }
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_gput_right:cV { g_pg_#2_clist } #3
   }
   {
    \clist_gput_right:cn { g_pg_#2_clist } { #3 }
   }
  \clist_gremove_duplicates:c { g_pg_#2_clist }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ShowList}{ m }
 {
  List~\texttt{#1}~contains\par
  \clist_map_inline:cn { g_pg_#1_clist } { ##1\par }
 }
\begin{document}
\NewList{duplicates}
\AddToList{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddToList{duplicates}{DEF}

\ShowList{duplicates}

\AddToList{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddToList{duplicates}{XYZ}

\ShowList{duplicates}

\newcommand{\mylist}{ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}

\AddToList*{duplicates}{\mylist}

\ShowList{duplicates}
\end{document}
```

The output will be

[image]

To be on the safe side, the macro `\AddToList` has a *-variant for giving a macro as the second argument.

Comment: I know that the `\foreach` groups things, but when I saw that the data was being added to the db and was still in the db after the `\foreach` I was not able to make sense of that.

Comment: Also, not able to figure out how to make the `\foreachin` work with a macro defined list.

Comment: @PeterGrill The data was added *before* the `\foreach`, I believe. For the list passed as a macro, I've added a variant.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure about the `datatool` usage, but if you just want to process a comma separated list I think that package is a lot more powerful than you need.  The following plain TeX produces

```
$ tex ll5
This is TeX, Version 3.1415926 (Web2C 2010)
(./ll5.tex
[ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM] -> [ABC,DEF,MMM,JHM]
[ABC] -> [ABC]
[] -> []
[xx, yyy, xx, yyy, sss] -> [xx,yyy,sss]
[xx] -> [xx]
[] -> []
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on ll5.log.
```

Showing the duplicates being removed, and some edge cases tested.

```
\def\removedups#1#2{%take list in #1 remove duplicates into #2
 \begingroup
  \def\temp##1{}%
  \expandafter\xrem#1,\relax
  \expandafter\endgroup
 \expandafter\def\expandafter#2\expandafter{\temp}}

\def\xrem#1,#2{%
 \expandafter\ifx\csname!!#1\endcsname\xrem\else
  \expandafter\let\csname!!#1\endcsname\xrem
  \edef\temp{\temp,#1}%
 \fi
 \ifx\relax#2\else
  \expandafter\xrem\expandafter#2%
 \fi}



\def\llll{ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}    
\removedups\llll\aA
\immediate\write20{[\llll] -> [\aA]}

\def\llll{ABC}    
\removedups\llll\aB
\immediate\write20{[\llll] -> [\aB]}

\def\llll{}
\removedups\llll\aC
\immediate\write20{[\llll] -> [\aC]}

\removedups{xx, yyy, xx, yyy, sss}\bA
\immediate\write20{[xx, yyy, xx, yyy, sss] -> [\bA]}

\removedups{xx}\bB
\immediate\write20{[xx] -> [\bB]}

\removedups{}\bC
\immediate\write20{[] -> [\bC]}



\bye
```

Answer (score 5):

`DTLgetlocation` ends with

```
\newcommand*{\DTLgetlocation}[4]{%
  % <snip>
  \ifx#1\dtlnovalue
    \PackageError{datatool}{There is no element `#4' in
      database `#3'}{}%
  \fi
}
```

which produces the error. One way would be to avoid this error by patching `\DTLgetlocation`, and then performing the equivalence test inside `\IfIsInDB`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}% http://ctan.org/pkg/datatool
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% Patch \DTLgetlocation to gobble the error
\patchcmd{\DTLgetlocation}% <cmd>
  {\PackageError}% <search>
  {\@gobbletwo}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\DBKey}{Value}%

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDuplicatesDB}[1]{% 
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}%
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[2]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = member to be added to DB
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{\DBKey}{#2}%
}%
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IfIsInDB}[4]{%
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    % #2 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
    % #3 = code to execute if member is in DB
    % #4 = code to execute if member is not in DB
    \DTLgetlocation{\RowIndex}{\ColIndex}{#1}{#2}%
    %row=\RowIndex \quad col=\ColIndex\par
    \expandafter\ifx\RowIndex\@dtlnovalue% No entry/duplicate found...
      #4%
      \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2}
    \else% ...a duplicate was found
%    \ifnum\RowIndex>0\relax%
      #3%
%    \fi
    \fi%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\InitalizeDuplicatesDB{duplicates}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{ABC}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{DEF}

Current db:
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip

\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{ABC}{ABC is a duplicate}{ABC added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{DEF}{DEF is a duplicate}{DEF added DB}\par    
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{XYZ}{XYZ is a duplicate}{XYZ added DB}\par

\medskip

Current db:
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
\end{document}
```

The patch from `\PackageError` to `\@gobbletwo` (in `\DTLgetlocation`) eats the first two arguments. However, the final empty group `{}` doesn't affect the output. Additionally, `\RowIndex` is defined as `\@dtlnovalue`, which we can use in comparison to check for an existing item (or not).

Comment: Thanks. This worked great for the initial test. I have expanded it further using a `\foreach` and does not seem to work for that case. I thought it was some scoping related issue, but the db prints out just fine. Note: This necessitated the addition of `\dtlexpandnewvalue` in `\IfIsInDB` -- if you forget to add this you will get `Undefined control sequence \@dtl@val ->\x` error.

Comment: The problem with `\foreach` is the usual one: each step is executed inside a group, so the changes to the database disappear. Just don't use `\foreach` for these tasks, but a "group-free" procedure, such as those defined by `etoolbox` or `expl3`.

Comment: Instead of `\expandafter\ifx\RowIndex\@dtlnovalue` it's better to use `\ifx\RowIndex\@@dtlnovalue`, with `\def\@@dtlnovalue{\@dtlnovalue}`; the test would fail if `\RowIndex` expands to a two (or more) digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is brute force solution: Modify `\IfIsInDB` to use a `\DTLforeach` to step thru the database and see if that value is found.  Not very elegant, but does appear to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=15in]{geometry}% so output fits on "one" page
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{pgffor}%   Added for expanded test

\newcommand*{\DBKey}{Value}%

\newcommand*{\InitalizeDuplicatesDB}[1]{% 
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    \DTLifdbexists{#1}%
        {\DTLcleardb{#1}}% DB exists, so just clear it
        {\DTLnewdb{#1}}%   DB does not exist, so create it
}%
\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[3]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = Key of column to add to
    % #3 = member to be added to DB
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%

\newtoggle{foundInDB}%
\newcommand*{\IfIsInDB}[5]{%
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    % #2 = Key of column to check
    % #3 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
    % #4 = code to execute if member is in DB
    % #5 = code to execute if member is not in DB
    %
    \dtlexpandnewvalue% Added in update.
    %
    \togglefalse{foundInDB}%
    \DTLforeach{#1}{\CurrentMember=#2}{%
        \IfEq{#3}{\CurrentMember}{% Found member
            \global\toggletrue{foundInDB}%
            \dtlbreak% Might as well break out of loop
        }{% Haven't found it yet, so keep looking....
        }%
    }%
    %\DTLgetlocation{\RowIndex}{\ColIndex}{#1}{#2}%
    \iftoggle{foundInDB}{%
        #4%
    }{%
        #5%
        \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\InitalizeDuplicatesDB{duplicates}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{ABC}
\AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{DEF}

Current db:\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{ABC}{ABC is a duplicate}{ABC added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{DEF}{DEF is a duplicate}{DEF added DB}\par
\IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{XYZ}{XYZ is a duplicate}{XYZ added DB}\par

\medskip
Current db (before foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

% Following tests added in update.
\medskip\par\noindent
Testing with a non-macro defined list (ABC, DEF should not be ``added", and MMM should only be ``added" once):\par
\foreach \x in {ABC, DEF, ABC, MMM, MMM, JHM}{%
    \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{\x}{\x~is a duplicate}{\x~added DB}\par
}%

Current db (after foreach - no macro):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\medskip\par\noindent
Testing with a macro defined list: (ABC, DEF should not be "added", and NNN should only be ``added" once)\par
\newcommand*{\ListMembers}{ABC, XXX, DEF, NNN, NNN, YYY}%
\foreach \x in \ListMembers {%
    \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\DBKey}{\x}{\x~is a duplicate}{\x~added DB}\par
}

Current db (after foreach - macro defn):\par
\DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
\end{document}
```