# Check if a datatool DB has an existing member

Tags: xparse, datatool, xstring

Using the code from [How to check if a datatool db has an existing member](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53323/how-to-check-if-a-datatool-db-has-an-existing-member) with the same problem (build a `datatool` DB with unique strings) it works well as long if there is not an additional level (here via `\DeclareDocumentCommand`) with the same functionality. Now the solution dosen't recognize the ABC string and add it again to the DB. The definition `\tmp` should be fully expanded (`xstring` User’s manual). The result should be only one string `ABC` in the `duplicates` DB.

The strings I need to bring in are assigned to various definitions several times before ending in a DB (a simplified MWE below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{xparse,xstring}

\makeatletter
% Patch \DTLgetlocation to gobble the error
\let\ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation\DTLgetlocation
\patchcmd{\ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation}% <cmd>
  {\PackageError}% <search>
  {\@gobbletwo}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\def\@@dtlnovalue{\@dtlnovalue} 

\newcommand*{\DBKey}{Value}

\newcommand*{\AddMemberToDB}[2]{%
    % #1 = name of DB
    % #2 = member to be added to DB
    \DTLnewrow{#1}%
    \DTLnewdbentry{#1}{\DBKey}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\IfIsInDB}[4]{% %New definition!
    % #1 = name to be used for this duplicate's DB
    % #2 = member to check if in DB (gets added if not)
    % #3 = code to execute if member is in DB
    % #4 = code to execute if member is not in DB
    \ErrorFreeDTLgetlocation{\RowIndex}{\ColIndex}{#1}{#2}%
    \ifx\RowIndex\@@dtlnovalue
        #4%
        \AddMemberToDB{#1}{#2}%
    \else
        #3
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\AddEntrytoDB}{m m}{
  \def\tmp{}
  \StrDel{#2}{ }[\tmp]% delete the spaces
  \IfIsInDB{#1}{\tmp}
    {CMD: \tmp is a duplicate}
    {CMD: \tmp\, added DB}
}

\begin{document}

  \def\ABC{A B C} % ABC string with spaces
  \def\varABC{}
  \StrDel{\ABC}{ }[\varABC]% delete the spaces

  \DTLnewdb{duplicates} % create new DB

  \AddMemberToDB{duplicates}{\varABC} % add ABC string w/o spaces to DB

  Current DB:\par % display the DB
  \DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}
  \medskip

  \IfIsInDB{duplicates}{\varABC} % check another ABC string w/o spaces
    {ABC is a duplicate}% Yes: is in
    {ABC added DB}% No: is not in, add it
  \par

  \AddEntrytoDB{duplicates}{\ABC} % add another ABC string via Command

  \medskip
  Current DB:\par % display the DB
  \DTLdisplaydb{duplicates}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you just need to add a `\dtlexpandnewvalue` to the `\AddMemberToDB`. I thought the code formatting looked familiar. :-)

Comment: @Peter: Unfortunately \dtlexpandnewvalue dosen't help. Now there are 3x ABC in the DB.

Comment: I think if you modify `\IfIsInDB` to include the line `\edef\@ExpandedTarget{#2}` and then use `\@ExpandedTarget` instead of `#2` and replace the call to `AddMemberToDB` with `\AddEntrytoDB`, things work as desired.

Comment: @Peter: In the first view it works well, but it looks that there is a different (expansion?) problem. Say we define `\def\efg{efg}` and add `\AddEntrytoDB{duplicates}{\efg}` to the document. The DB should now contain 2 entries, but every additional entry is a duplicate and only the last definition is in the DB. It looks that the DB stores the definition of  '\@ExpandedTarget' and not it's value.

Comment: I think I found at lest one problem: You need to compare to `\@dtlnovalue`, not `\@@dtlnovalue`.