# Using LaTeX to compact a list of numbers

Tags: macros

This a bit out of ordinary. But has anybody used LaTeX to compact a list of numbers?

The closest example that comes to mind is the way the citation numbers are compressed and 
sorted using the [cite](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/cite) package. So, if I write `\cite{key1, key2, key3, key4, key5}`, we get something like 1-3, 7, 9.

The situation under consideration is almost similar, except the numbers are real numbers or expanded to real numbers, not citation keys. So, if I write `\compactthis{1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7, 11}`, I will get 1-5, 7-9, 11.

Is there a quick way of achieving this? Writing macros from scratch will take time which I can not afford at this moment.

(I understand that programming languages are better suited for this, but my current situation demands the use of LaTeX.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDITED to sort the input stream** using a bubble sort (the macro `\bubblesort` can be used independently of the `\compactthis` macro, if desired).

A `\listterminator` must be set to *ANY* numerical value known not to be in the list (e.g., suitably large, negative, zero, etc.), currently set at `9999`.  As shown (both in code and demonstrated in the MWE), the macro `\adjtie` can be set to `--` if `1--2` is preferred to `1, 2` for adjacent limiting entries.

**No packages required.**

```
\documentclass{article}
%
% THIS CODE CAN \bubblesort A NUMBERED LIST AND THEN \compactthis LIST IN THE MANNER
% OF 1-3, 7, 11-13
%
\def\listterminator{9999}% SET TO *ANY* VALUE KNOWN NOT TO BE IN LIST (POSITIVE OR NEGATIVE)
\def\adjtie{, }
%\def\adjtie{--}% OPTIONAL IF 1--2 preferred over 1, 2
\newcommand\compactthis[1]{%
  \bubblesort{#1}%
  \expandafter\begincompaction\sortedlist,\listterminator,\relax%
}
\def\begincompaction#1,#2\relax{%
  \def\startlist{#1}%
  \def\currentendlist{#1}%
  \findendlist#2\relax%
}
\def\findendlist#1,#2\relax{%
  \ifnum\numexpr\currentendlist+1\relax=#1\relax%
    \def\currentendlist{#1}%
    \findendlist#2\relax%
  \else%
    \ifnum\startlist=\currentendlist\relax%
      \ignorespaces\startlist\unskip%
    \else%
      \ifnum\numexpr\startlist+1\relax=\currentendlist\relax%
        \ignorespaces\startlist\unskip\adjtie\ignorespaces\currentendlist\unskip%
      \else%
        \ignorespaces\startlist\unskip--\ignorespaces\currentendlist\unskip%
      \fi%
    \fi%
    \ifnum#1=\listterminator\else,\ \begincompaction#1,#2\relax\fi%
  \fi%
}
\newcommand\bubblesort[1]{\def\sortedlist{}\sortlist#1,\listterminator,\relax}
\def\sortlist#1,#2,#3\relax{%
  \ifnum#2=\listterminator\relax%
    \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1}%
  \else
    \ifnum#1<#2\relax%
      \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1,}%
      \sortlist#2,#3\relax%
    \else%
      \let\tmp\sortedlist%
      \def\sortedlist{}%
      \expandafter\sortlist\tmp#2,#1,#3\relax%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
Bubble Sort Demonstration: 
\bubblesort{1,2,11, 7, 4, 3}\sortedlist\par
\compactthis{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9, 11}\par
\compactthis{1,2, 12 ,13 ,18, 20} (single member)\par
\compactthis{1,2, 12,13,18, 19, 20} (range at end)\par
\def\adjtie{--}\compactthis{1,2, 12,13,18, 19, 20} (\verb|\adjtie| set to {--})\par
\compactthis{1,2,11, 7, 4, 3, 12, 14, 13} (unsorted input)
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A comprehensive solution ready-to-use.

Comment: @Masroor Thank you.  I appreciate the consideration and endorsement.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the bulk of what you need with the input in black and the output in red:

[image]

### Notes:

- The main thing missing here is to sort the initial list. There are numerous solutions on this site, but one I have been using is [Sorting Comma Separated Lists defined with, or without macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52640/sorting-comma-separated-lists-defined-with-or-without-macro). Another one is: [How to sort an alphanumeric list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6988/how-to-sort-an-alphanumeric-list)
- This also needs furhter testing for cases that were not tested.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newtoggle{StartedRange}
\newcommand{\LastNumber}{}%
\newcommand{\LastRangeStart}{}%
\newcommand*{\compactthis}[1]{%
    \edef\ExpandedParam{#1}% <-- Apply sorting here
    \ExpandedParam:
    \begingroup\color{red}%
    \togglefalse{StartedRange}%
    \foreach \x in \ExpandedParam {%
        \iftoggle{StartedRange}{%
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\ExpectedNextNumber{\LastNumber+1}%
            \IfEq{\ExpectedNextNumber}{\x}{%
                %% Continue this range
            }{%
                \IfEq{\LastRangeStart}{\LastNumber}{%
                    %% Was a single member
                }{%
                    --\LastNumber% Close last range
                }%
                ,\, \x%        and start a new range
                \xdef\LastRangeStart{\x}%
            }%
       }{%
            \x% initial range
            \xdef\LastRangeStart{\x}%
            \global\toggletrue{StartedRange}%
        }%
        \xdef\LastNumber{\x}%
    }%
    %  Process any ranges at end of list:
    \IfEq{\LastRangeStart}{\LastNumber}{%
        %% Was a single member
    }{%
        --\LastNumber% Close last range
    }%
    \endgroup%
}%

\begin{document}
\compactthis{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9, 11}

\compactthis{1,2, 12,13,18, 20}% Single member

\compactthis{1,2, 12,13,18, 19, 20}% range at end

\end{document}
```

Comment: Highly procedural approach :) I'm looking forward to someone posting a functional solution (I'm really not able to do that myself)

Comment: @yo': Yep, but gets the job done. :-)

Comment: It wasn't criticism! It was just ... well ... a comment; I'd really like to see a functional answer...

Comment: Also, I'd not "compactify" `1, 2` to `1--2`, but that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a LuaLaTeX solution. Because Lua has an easy-to-use sorting function (`table.sort`), it also sorts the input list. There are probably ways to make the Lua code more concise, but it should be easy to understand for anyone familiar with imperative programming languages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function print_range(range_min, range_max)
  if range_min == range_max then
    tex.sprint(tostring(range_min))
  else
    tex.sprint(tostring(range_min) .. "--" .. tostring(range_max))
  end
end
function compactthis(...)
  local numbers = {...}
  table.sort(numbers)
  local range_started = false
  local range_min = 0
  local range_max = 0
  for i = 1, #numbers do
    if range_started then
      if numbers[i] <= range_max + 1 then
        range_max = numbers[i]
      else
        print_range(range_min, range_max)
        range_started = false
      end
    end
    if not range_started then
      if i ~= 1 then
        tex.sprint(", ")
      end
      range_started = true
      range_min = numbers[i]
      range_max = numbers[i]
    end
  end
  if range_started then
    print_range(range_min, range_max)
  end
end
\end{luacode*}
\newcommand\compactthis[1]{\luaexec{compactthis(#1)}}

\begin{document}
\compactthis{1,2,3,4,5,9,8,7,11}
\end{document}
```