# Sorting a description

Tags: sorting, description

I want to sort a description list in an alphabetical order.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[bb] \hfill \\ something bb
  \item[aa] \hfill \\ something aa
  \item[dd] \hfill \\ something dd
  \item[cc] \hfill \\ something cc
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is really a multi-pronged question.  There are various questions about sorting of lists, for example, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333646/sorting-a-comma-separated-list-with-latex.  However, that in itself does not address the parsing of your environment to find the list of things to sort.

Comment: What's the `\hfill` for if you put a new line immediately after it?

Comment: yes. I put \hfill to do so.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121489/alphabetically-display-the-items-in-itemize is not working for descriptions. That is only for itemize. Could you help me to sort the description? Thanks.