# Trying to eliminate stack overflow during recursion (Alphabetic Bubble Sorter)

Tags: sorting, recursion

I was looking at this question, [Order table by row alphabeticaly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372603/order-table-by-row-alphabeticaly), and thought, "that OP needs some sort of bubble sorter."

I had done a numerical bubble sorter here, [Using LaTeX to compact a list of numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326115/using-latex-to-compact-a-list-of-numbers/326133#326133) (it actually sorted reference numbers and also compacted sequential references) and saw that I had also done an alpha-bubble sorter, as well here, [Sorting a comma-separated list with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333646/sorting-a-comma-separated-list-with-latex/333659#333659).

Unfortunately, I discovered that the alpha-bubble sorter was prone to stack overflow from the recursion, when the list became larger.  So I endeavored to streamline things here, rewriting the code.  It is able to handle larger list sizes than the cited version, but as seen the included MWE, if I uncomment that one additional item in the list (`encontrar`), I blow the stack.

Now I know that, in theory, the way to avoid blowing the stack during a conditional recursion is to `...\expandafter\recursion\fi`.  However, I've never been good at mastering that technique when the recursion is nested deep in an `\if` block, nor when the recursion is not a mere macro name, but instead a `...\recursion<data-block>\relax\fi` blob.

David C tells me that the stack size is set in texmf.cnf, and while I haven't yet found that file in my MikTeX installation, I realize that enlarging the stack is a poor fix in lieu of better code.

I also have not yet put in the `\the\lccode` tweaks to overlook lettercase in the search, but one thing at a time.

I figure a general LaTeX alpha-bubble sorter would be a useful thing to more than just me, so I post it here as a question, in hopes that it can be beat into submission and become a useful tool.

In the MWE below, the routine `\alphabubblesorter` calls on `\sortlist` to do the primary bubble sort, with `\picknext` being called upon for cases that share the same first letter.  So `\sortlist` is recursive through the data list, and `\picknext` is recursive through the letter list of two comparitive entries.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand\alphabubblesort[1]{\def\sortedlist{}\expandafter\sortlist#1,9,\relax}
\def\sortlist#1#2,#3#4,#5\relax{%
  \ifnum`#3=`9\relax%
    \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2}%
  \else
    \ifnum`#1<`#3\relax%
      \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2,}%
      \sortlist#3#4,#5\relax%
    \else%
      \ifnum`#1>`#3\relax%
        \let\tmp\sortedlist%
        \def\sortedlist{}%
        \expandafter\sortlist\tmp#3#4,#1#2,#5\relax%
      \else%
        \picknext#2!,#4!\relax%
        \if F\flipflop%
          \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2,}%
          \sortlist#3#4,#5\relax%
        \else%
          \let\tmp\sortedlist%
          \def\sortedlist{}%
          \expandafter\sortlist\tmp#3#4,#1#2,#5\relax%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\picknext#1#2,#3#4\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1<`#3\relax
    \xdef\flipflop{F}%
  \else%
    \ifnum`#1>`#3\relax%
      \xdef\flipflop{T}%
    \else%
      \picknext#2!,#4!\relax%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\alphabubblesort{da,cc,ca,eda,edc,edb,ef,ec,ed,eb,edzq,ba,e,fa,waaa,wa,qa}\sortedlist

\def\mydata{%
Spanish     ,
ser         ,
haber       ,
estar       ,
tener       ,
hacer       ,
poder       ,
decir       ,
ir          ,
ver         ,
dar         ,
saber       ,
querer      ,
llegar      ,
pasar       ,
deber       ,
poner       ,
parecer     ,
quedar      ,
creer       ,
hablar      ,
llevar      ,
dejar       ,
seguir      ,
%encontrar   ,
llamar       }
\alphabubblesort{\mydata}\sortedlist
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what test input should i use to test (not) blowing the stack)

Comment: There is (upon edit) a commented line in the last data entry (`encontrar`).  Commented, it works; uncommented, it breaks.

Comment: ah spotted.......

Comment: I see problems if there's ñ in the list. Accents should not be a problem with verbs.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I know my other alpha-sorter did some additional expansions to handle diacritics.  I will have to consider that next...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like this allows the parameter stack to be popped before the recursive call

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand\alphabubblesort[1]{\def\sortedlist{}\expandafter\sortlist#1,zzzzzzzzzz,\relax}
\def\sortlist#1#2,#3#4,#5\relax{%
  \let\next\relax
  \ifnum`#3=`z\relax%
    \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2}%
  \else
    \ifnum`#1<`#3\relax%
      \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2,}%
      \def\next{\sortlist#3#4,#5\relax}%
    \else%
      \ifnum`#1>`#3\relax%
        \let\tmp\sortedlist%
        \def\sortedlist{}%
        \def\next{\expandafter\sortlist\tmp#3#4,#1#2,#5\relax}%
      \else%
        \picknext#2!,#4!\relax%
        \if F\flipflop%
          \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1#2,}%
           \def\next{\sortlist#3#4,#5\relax}%
        \else%
          \let\tmp\sortedlist%
          \def\sortedlist{}%
          \def\next{\expandafter\sortlist\tmp#3#4,#1#2,#5\relax}%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\next
}
\def\picknext#1#2,#3#4\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1<`#3\relax
    \xdef\flipflop{F}%
  \else%
    \ifnum`#1>`#3\relax%
      \xdef\flipflop{T}%
    \else%
      \ZZfifi{\picknext#2!,#4!\relax}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\ZZfifi#1\fi\fi{\fi\fi#1}

\begin{document}
\alphabubblesort{30,2c,2a,4da,4dc,4db,4f,4c,4d,2b,4dzq,10,4,50,W0,w0,q0}\sortedlist

\def\mydata{%
Spanish     ,
ser         ,
haber       ,
estar       ,
tener       ,
hacer       ,
poder       ,
decir       ,
ir          ,
ver         ,
dar         ,
saber       ,
querer      ,
llegar      ,
pasar       ,
deber       ,
poner       ,
parecer     ,
quedar      ,
creer       ,
hablar      ,
llevar      ,
dejar       ,
seguir      ,
encontrar   ,
llamar       }
\alphabubblesort{\mydata}\sortedlist
\end{document}
```

---

I hate to meddle in David's amazing answer (Steven here), but I realized I could streamline things further by going directly to `\picknext`.  I also added the `\the\lccode` bit to screen out lettercase.

So, in this incarnation, `\sortlist` merely performs the swap of two adjacent list items, if appropriate, whereas `\picknext` makes the decision on whether the swap should be made. (`\sortlist` no longer compares anything except for the end of list condition).

Since David was too modest to lay out the specifics of his changes, I will just call reader attention to his use of `\next`, which is a not so unusual way of moving stuff outside of a nested `\if` structure.  But the crowning glory comes with his creation and use of `\ZZfifi`, which (if I understand it) absorbs the remaining two `\fi`s of the current recursion, and then pops 2 of them off the stack as the first step in the next recursion.  Masterful!

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\newcommand\alphabubblesort[1]{\def\sortedlist{}\expandafter\sortlist#1,\cr,\relax}
\def\sortlist#1,#2,#3\relax{%
  \let\next\relax
  \ifx\cr#2\relax%
    \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1}%
  \else
    \picknext#1!,#2!\relax%
    \if F\flipflop%
      \edef\sortedlist{\sortedlist#1,}%
      \def\next{\sortlist#2,#3\relax}%
    \else%
      \let\tmp\sortedlist%
      \def\sortedlist{}%
      \def\next{\expandafter\sortlist\tmp#2,#1,#3\relax}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
\next
}
\def\picknext#1#2,#3#4\relax{%
  \ifnum\the\lccode`#1<\the\lccode`#3\relax
    \xdef\flipflop{F}%
  \else%
    \ifnum\the\lccode`#1>\the\lccode`#3\relax%
      \xdef\flipflop{T}%
    \else%
      \ZZfifi{\picknext#2!,#4!\relax}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\ZZfifi#1\fi\fi{\fi\fi#1}
\begin{document}
\alphabubblesort{da,cc,ca,eda,edc,edb,ef,ec,ed,eb,edzq,ba,e,fa,waaa,wa,qa}\sortedlist

\def\mydata{
Spanish, ser, haber, estar, tener, hacer, poder, decir, ir, ver, dar, saber, querer,
llegar, pasar, deber, poner, parecer, quedar, creer, hablar, llevar, dejar,
seguir, encontrar, llamar}
\alphabubblesort{\mydata}\sortedlist
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will take a while for me to chew on, because you have some really neat tricks here.  I get the one with `\next`, but I am trying to wrap my mind around`\ZZfifi`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I like to give commands self explanatory names.

Comment: Well I know that if it has a `Z` it is special, and so I know that 2 `Z`s are the cat's meow.  BTW, I edited your answer to add the `\the\lccode` fix for lettercase.

Comment: `\ZZfifi` is a magnificent achievement in stack manipulation.  I applaud your ingenuity.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes sure it wasn't my idea: more "common folklore";-)