# How do I process a command parameter into a certain number of characters?

Tags: macros

Currently, I’m in the process of writing a travel guide and I’d like to include general price information next to the locations and events, e.g.

$$$$ - Fancy Expensive Steakhouse

I figured that since I’d be doing this a lot it’d be a good idea to make a little command to insert an arbitrary number of dollar signs instead of individually escaping each dollar sign, but for the life of me I couldn’t figure it out.

Ideally, I’d want the command to go something like

```
\price{4}
```

To insert 4 dollar signs like in the above. I feel like I’m missing something simple, but after googling various variations of my question and looking into tex macros (unfortunately unfruitfully) I’m still at a loss. I’d also like to be able to format the dollar symbols (in gray for instance), but I feel like I can do that by defining an environment around the `\price` command once I get it working.

Any help or pointers to relative documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to separate `\price` and `\pricesymbol`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pricesymbol}{}{\textcolor{black!60}{\$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\price}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { \pricesymbol }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\price{4} -- Fancy Expensive Steakhouse

\price{2} -- Pizza House (no pineapple)

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can even have fractional price symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pricesymbol}{}{\textcolor{black!60}{\$}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\price}{m}
 {
  \prg_replicate:nn { \fp_eval:n { trunc(#1,0) } } { \pricesymbol }
  \fp_compare:nT { #1 - trunc(#1,0) > 0 }
   {
    \clipbox{0~0~{\fp_eval:n { 1 - #1 + trunc(#1,0) }\width}~0} { \pricesymbol } \,
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\price{4} -- Fancy Expensive Steakhouse

\price{2} -- Pizza House (no pineapple)

\price{2.3} -- Pizza House (no pineapple)

\price{2.5} -- Pizza House (no pineapple)

\price{2.7} -- Pizza House (no pineapple)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't even aware that you could have partial symbols, thanks! Using overleaf, I had to also add a `\usepackage{xparse}`, maybe since it is using Latex2e instead of Latex3?

Comment: xparse has been built in to latex since this year's realease, using xparse package with an older latex is essentially the same @Herschenglime

Comment: Can you have Pizza without pineapple?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

One way is to have a simple recursion on the number

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\price[1]{\ifnum#1>0\$\price{\numexpr#1-1\relax}\fi}

\price{1}  zzz

\price{20} ZZZ

\end{document}
```

Comment: Darn.  Beat me by 15 sec

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes and I printed more $

Comment: Surely, a bargain at any price!

Comment: Nice construction. Just to be sure, that is not tail recursion, isn't it? Then it ought to be something like \expandafter\price\fi? This macro will be building up on the stack?

Comment: @RaoulKessels yes true but I figured you wouldn't have more that 10 or so iterations so the extra code to make it tail recursive would complicate the answer for no great benefit

Comment: @RaoulKessels `\newcommand\price[1]{\iftrue\priceaux#1\fi}
\def\priceaux#1\fi{\fi\ifnum#1>0 \$\expandafter\priceaux\expandafter{\numexpr#1-1}\fi}`  Note the `\expandafter`s are optional.  The absorption of `\fi` by `\priceaux` makes it a "tail recursion"

Comment: @RaoulKessels I learned the `\fi` trick from an old-timer named...David Carlisle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/372639/trying-to-eliminate-stack-overflow-during-recursion-alphabetic-bubble-sorter/372644#372644

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't mean that it was incorrect or something like that. I just wanted to make sure if I had understood the answers here: tex.stackexchange.com/questions/359189/looping-over-strings

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I knew it could be done ;-) Now I will have to study how it works. Thx

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The `\expandafter`s "hitting" `\numexpr` have no effect because `\numexpr` is not expandable. `\number`, however,  is expandable...

Comment: @UlrichDiez Wow, that is news to me.  Yet, `\the\numexpr` is expandable?  If so, then I just need to add `\the` to my code

Comment: @RaoulKessels I was a bit shocked to discover from Ulrich that `\numexpr` is not expandable, even though I know `\the\numexpr` to be expandable.  What this means for the code I provided in the earlier comment is that I should have the braced expression as `{\the\numexpr#1-1}` in order for the `\expandafter`s to have an effect (or, as Ulrich suggested, `{\number\numexpr#1-1}`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\the` and `\number` are expandable. Thus you can do `\the\numexpr...` or `\number\numexpr...`, just as you like. With `\dimexpr` etc you need to use `\the`.

Comment: @UlrichDiez I learn something new every day.  Thank you.  Now if we could only get an implementation of `\the\unhbox`...all would be well, LOL.

Comment: @UlrichDiez while the result is the same, `\the\numexpr` is (around 10%) faster than `\number\numexpr` (there is a difference however between `\number\dimexpr` and `\the\dimexpr`).

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\numexpr` on its own isn't expandable, it is more or less the same as using `\count`, just that it computes the value on the fly based on the input instead of fetching it from a register.

Comment: Thank you @Skillmon for adding content about `\numexpr`!

Comment: Ok, the 10% estimate was a little low. `\the` is more like 30% faster.

Answer (score 2):

Tail-recursive, only traditional TeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\priceloop[1]{\if#1m\$\expandafter\priceloop\fi}
\newcommand\price[1]{\expandafter\priceloop\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\relax}

\begin{document}

\price{12}

\end{document}
```

Tail-recursive, eTeX-extensions:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\price[1]{\ifnum#1>0 \exchange{\$\expandafter\price\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1\relax}}\fi}

\begin{document}

\price{12}

\end{document}
```

Or use one of [David Kastrup's `\replicate`-variants:](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls/2005p/david-kastrup/bachotex2005-david-kastrup-pearl3.pdf)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\gobble[1]{}
\newcommand\xii[2]{\if#2m#1\expandafter\xii\else\expandafter\gobble\fi{#1}}
\newcommand\xiii[2]{\xii{#2}#1\relax}
\newcommand\replicate[1]{\expandafter\xiii\expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}}%

\newcommand\price[1]{\replicate{#1}{\$}}

\begin{document}

\price{12}

\end{document}
```

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\recur[1]{\csname rn#1\recur}
\newcommand\rnm[1]{\endcsname{#1}#1}
\newcommand\rn[1]{}
\newcommand\replicate[1]{\csname rn\expandafter\recur\romannumeral\number\number#1 000\endcsname\endcsname}

\newcommand\price[1]{\replicate{#1}{\$}}

\begin{document}

\price{12}

\end{document}
```

The sequence `\romannumeral\number\number#1 000` instead of just `\romannumeral#1000` is for the following reason:

`#1` is to be some TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity that is to be multiplied by 1000 by attaching digits `000` so that `\romannumeral` delivers the corresponding amount of character-tokens `m`.

`#1` is not necessarily a sequence of digits.

It could be a `\count`-register as well where you need a space-token for separating the number denoting the `\count`-register from the three zeros to attach to the tokens forming the value held in that `\count`-register:

Assume you wish to denote the value held in `\count`-register 17:

`\romannumeral\count17000` will not work out because TeX assumes an attempt of denoting the value held in `\count`-register 17000 and raises an error as there is no `\count`-register 17000.

`\romannumeral\number\number\count17 000` does work out:

The second `\number` delivers the value that is held in `\count`-register 17 as digit-sequence. The space behind `17`/before `000` is consumed as end-marker of the digit-sequence `17` denoting the `\count`-register.

The first `\number` is not needed here/does not change the fact that when the second `\number` is finished you already have a digit-sequence with three zeros appended which can be processed by `\romannumeral`.

But the TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity could be a `\countdef`-token or a `\chardef`-token or the like as well whereafter a space-token will not be removed by TeX.

Assume someone doing `` \chardef\sixtyfive=`\A ``.
`\romannumeral\sixtyfive000` will not work out because due to TeX's rules for gathering TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantities with `\chardef`-tokens `000` will not be considered part of the number to be processed by `\romannumeral`.

But `\romannumeral\number\number\sixtyfive⟨space-token⟩000` will work out:

The second `\number` delivers `65` from the chardef-token `\sixtyfive`. This `65` is trailed by the *⟨space-token⟩* and the three zeros. The first `\number` finds the digit-sequence `65` trailed by a *⟨space-token⟩* and eliminates that *⟨space-token⟩*. Now `\romannumeral` as number to convert can gather `65000` and deliver 65 characters `m`.

Comment: I have understood the first one. At first I did not understand how it could work without any -1. The \if is comparing a bunch of mmmmmm... and every cycle one is added and two are gobbled, not? Very nice. But why the two \number? If I take out one it seems to work the same. I can take out both if I write \romannumeral#1000

Comment: @RaoulKessels I added explanation for the two `\number` to my answer.||The gist of the first one is: Behind the token `\priceloop` you get characters `m` in an amount corresponding to `\price`'s `#1`, trailed by `\relax`. The tail-recursive macro `\priceloop` gathers an argument, via `\if` compares its  character-code to the character-code of `m`. Only if character-codes are equal both `\$` is delivered and `\priceloop`  calls itself again. So the trailing `\relax`, which as control-sequence in `\if`-comparisons is assumed to have a character-code which no character has, terminates the loop.

Comment: @RaoulKessels The characters `m` in an amount corresponding to `\price`'s `#1` are delivered by `\romannumeral` - attaching `000` means multiplying by 1000. 1000 is m in roman notation. Multiples of 1000 are multiple m in roman notation...

Comment: Thx for your very thorough explanation. That makes it clear