# Effiency and speed of expl3 "datatypes"

Tags: expl3

*Context:* For teaching purposes I'm planning to implement a binary tree in expl3 (please no "implement-it-in-another-language-comments"). I wonder whether to use token lists or clists or something different.

*Observation:* While browsing some questions here, there are again and again comments like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40031/how-to-process-a-comma-separated-list#comment80999_40037) about the speed of some expl3 methods. The interesting thing is that not all of those methods are documented in `interface3.pdf`.

*Question:* Is the processing of specific argument specifiers (or their conversions) slower than others and are some "datatypes" (clist, seq, str, tl) faster than others?

If it is too broad (because it sounds like "How to speed up l3 code") then please mention it in the comments and I try to ask about specific methods.

Comment: Tangential to the question itself, you might want to look at Bruno's experiments with binary trees: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/master/l3trial/l3tree

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks, I'll definitely have a look at it.

Comment: `l3prop` is ultra slow compared to TeX's own hashtable.

Comment: Given that there is no clean way currently to nest sequences, you're much better off using tls of length 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three things to bear in mind here. First, at a fundamental level `expl3` cannot extend the raw data types available in TeX itself: macros, registers and a few other special cases (case-changing codes, font dimensions, *etc.*). Second, the implementation detail of `expl3` can and has changed: the documented interfaces are what is stable. So any answer here could change. Finally, 'efficiency' can mean differing things. One can worry about efficiency in csname usage, speed of random access, speed of mapping, *etc.* and these things may depend on the likely scale.

All that said, we can examine the data types *as they are now*. The most basic is the `tl`, which is a wrapper around storage in macros. This can hold 'anything' but has no pre-defined structure. Essentially these are as fast as one can store tokens. (There is a wrinkle here: `tl` data is stored with in primitive terms `\edef{\unexpanded{<content>}}`, which allows `#` tokens but is *very* slightly slower than `\toks<number>={<content}`.)

Other data types holding tokens are (currently) implemented as single `tl` holders with internal structure. This is most obvious for `clist` (which is largely a shortcut for user input manipulation) but is also true for `seq` and `prop`. (Note: the latter has had at least three different implementations over the years.) The `prop` case illustrates well the question of 'What does efficiency mean?': using one `csname` per `prop` means you can have lots of `prop` data, but makes them slower for large numbers of keyvals than alternatives. This optimisation in terms of name usage was the original reason for having the data type (in the pre-e-TeX days), but also means they are fast to copy, *etc.*

For specialist applications there are often clever tricks that can speed up data access. For example, Bruno has recently added a fast integer array structure for supporting `l3regex`, which uses `fontdimen` data at the core. These though can be tricky to fully explain to others.

The team have worked on more flexible data structures including working out balances of different forms of efficiency. Probably if you want implementation advice you are best to ask on LaTeX-L or of course consult `source3`.

Answer (score 8):

Generally you'd expect seq to be more efficient than clist as it's set up internally for processing sequences, conversely clist is a comma separated list so it's set up for convenient user input with comma separators that then need to be parsed/removed to iterate over the list.  str/tl aren't really comparable as they are not implementing any kind of list data structure.

In some sense of course everything is a tl really as token lists are TeX's only real structure.

But if you just need a dataype of pairs to build a binary tree, whether to use two item tl or two item seq is a matter of choice, tl gives you essentially nothing and you would need to build your binary datatype up. seq would give you more functions for iterating over the sequence and selecting items, but may be overkill if all your sequences are of length two.

You might also want to consider modelling a tree using prop with left and right properties which may be more readable.

Comment: Well, you can use the tokens in a tl, can't you? That's a list for me.

Comment: @TeXnician yes you can but expl3 won't help much it doesn't give any particular list-like datatypes for iterating or selecting items of a token list thought of as a list in that sense. just assigning then or appending to each end.